# How to check whether a character comes before another character in a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that determines whether a math equation input by user has matching parentheses. I have it to where it counts whether the amount of right parentheses are equal to the amount of left parentheses, but the user could input 2)*(3+x)(4+x)*(6. To avoid telling the user his parentheses match in this case, I want to check if a ')' comes before a '('.

```
left_parenth = math.count("(")
right_parenth = math.count(")")

total_parenth = right_parenth + left_parenth

if total_parenth % 2 != 0:
    if right_parenth > left_parenth:
        print("\nYou are missing a left parentheses '('")
    elif right_parenth < left_parenth:
        print("\nYou are missing a right parentheses ')'")

elif total_parenth % 2 == 0:
    print("\nYour equation has the correct amount of parentheses")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

General idea here is to use stack.
When you encounter a opening parentheses, PUSH it on stack
When you encounter a closing parentheses, POP cooresponding opening parentheses from stack

Answer (score 0):

Using a stack is definitely not necessary. Just keep a count of how many parentheses are open. If that count ever is negative, then they aren't matched, and if the count ends up positive, they aren't matched:

```
def valid_parens(string):
    open_count = 0
    for char in string:
        if char == "(":
            open_count += 1
        elif char == ")":
            open_count -= 1
            if open_count < 0:
                return False
    return open_count == 0
```

Test cases:

```
assert valid_parens("((2+2)-4)*2") == True
assert valid_parens(")(2/2)(") == False
assert valid_parens("()()()") == True
assert valid_parens("((())") == False
```

Comment: Hah! -- except for our choice in variable names the code is exactly identical.  Goes to prove the old Python idiom, "There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it.".  :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the problem can be solved with a stack, it's a little wasteful of memory.  In normal-sized inputs this wouldn't ever be a problem, but in really large sequences it would become a problem.  You don't need to keep track of the parens themselves, but just a count of how many open ones there are -- total memory usage is a single integer, rather than one entry on a stack per paren encountered.

```
def proper_paren(seq):
    open_parens = 0
    for char in seq:
        if char == '(':
            open_parens += 1
        elif char == ')':
            open_parens -= 1
            if open_parens < 0:
                return False
    return open_parens == 0
```